# How do I generate an android debug.keystore from the command-line?

Tags: android, linux, command-line, android-emulator

I'm using a GUI-less linux so I can't use Eclipse to generate one for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

look at Android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) for creating a keystore using keytool.  They provide an example command:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Edit:  Sorry, I read too quickly.  If you want to use a debug keystore from the command line, you need to compile using "ant".